# ILocationListener.OnLocationChanged() method is NOT invoked when the device is not moving with Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I need to capture GPS location every second even when the device is still and not moving.

However, `OnLocationChanged()` method below is NOT invoked when the device is not moving.

```
 public class GpsLocationProvider : Java.Lang.Object, IGpsLocationProvider, ILocationListener
    {
        public event EventHandler<GpsLocationReceivedEventArgs> GpsLocationReceived;

        private LocationManager _locationManager;

        //call this method from other method to register during init.
        public void StartLocationUpdates(long minLocationUpdateIntervalInMs)
        {          
            if (_locationManager == null)
            {
                _locationManager = (LocationManager)Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.LocationService);
            }

            _locationManager.RequestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GpsProvider, 1000, 0, this);
        }

        public void StopLocationUpdates()
        {

            _locationManager?.RemoveUpdates(this);
        }

        #region ILocationListener Implementation

        public void OnLocationChanged(Location location)
        {
            if (GpsLocationReceived != null)
            {
                var gpsLocation = CreateLocation(location);

                GpsLocationReceived(this, new GpsLocationReceivedEventArgs(gpsLocation));
            }
        }

        public void OnProviderDisabled(string provider){ }

        public void OnProviderEnabled(string provider){}

        public void OnStatusChanged(string provider, [GeneratedEnum] Availability status, Bundle extras){}
        #endregion
    }
```

Xamarin Android ver 8

Lollipop 21

**Update:**

Google Play service is not available. Thus FusedLocationProvider is not avaialble.

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently using [GeolocatorPlugin by James Montemagno](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/GeolocatorPlugin) to solve a similar problem.
The [background update](https://jamesmontemagno.github.io/GeolocatorPlugin/BackgroundUpdates.html) part of this plugin allows you to set it to trigger for a timespan or a distance traveled. So even if the user hasn't moved in the timespan it will still get a location. So it should solve you wanting the location every second even if the user hasn't moved.

Note 1:
If you want this to run on the background for Android you are going to have to stick it in a foreground service.

Note 2:
As an added note. My usecase asks for the location every 10 seconds or every 10 meters. Over 10 minutes these are quite a lot of locations. So I dont send the location every update but rather save it in a local SQLlite, the records get send to the server when a certain amount of locations are saved or when the user stops the tracking. Given that you want to get the location every second you will have even more locations so this may be something to consider.

If you have further questions feel free to ask.

Comment: I want to understand why it is not working given that the statement ` _locationManager.RequestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GpsProvider, 1000, 0, this);` specifies to capture location every second even the distance is zero.

Comment: From what i can read on the android documentation is that the LocationListener's onLocationChanged only gets called when the location is actually different from the last time, which would make sense if you take the method name litteraly. The plugin i linked above always returns a location if either time or distance are met and not only if they are met AND the location has changed.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you give `FusedLocationProviderClient` a try, I am still confused why google hasn't deprecated `ILocationListener` yet anyway. As the name suggests it's a 'fused' location provider, it uses a mixture of GPS and network provided location to give you a trade-off between accuracy and battery consumption. It can also be updated independently of the OS, so it has a shorter release cycle for updates.

Well basically you need a subclass of the location callback:

```
    public class FusedLocationProviderCallback : LocationCallback
{
    readonly MainActivity activity;

    public FusedLocationProviderCallback(MainActivity activity)
    {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    public override void OnLocationAvailability(LocationAvailability locationAvailability)
    {
        Log.Debug("FusedLocationProviderSample", "IsLocationAvailable: {0}",locationAvailability.IsLocationAvailable);
    }


    public override void OnLocationResult(LocationResult result)
    {
        if (result.Locations.Any())
        {
            var location = result.Locations.FirstOrDefault();
          //Do something
        }
        else
        {
           //Do something else if no location received.
        }
    }
}
```

And then get your location client setup something like this https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/blob/master/FusedLocationProvider/FusedLocationProvider/MainActivity.cs

Comment: Google Play service is not available. Thus FusedLocationProvider is not avaialble.

Comment: Try this out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/maps-and-location/location

Comment: That is already used. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/maps-and-location/location#using-the-android-location-service-api

Comment: So you have the play services base? Referenced in your Android project?

Comment: NO, only use ILocationListener.